# I need help to write the rspec test in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I have a items_controller.rb

```
  def get_serialized_copy_of_item
    @item= Item.find_by_id(params[:id]) 
    if @item.nil?
      head :no_content
    else
      respond_to do |format|
      serialized_item = @item.as_json(include: [:test1, :test2, :test3, :test4])
      format.html
      format.json { render json: serialized_item }  
      end
    end
  end
```

routes.rb

```
namespace :items do
  get '/get_serialized_copy_of_item/:id', to:'items#get_serialized_copy_of_item'
end
```

I want to write a rspec test

1. submit incorrect item id and make sure that 204 is returned

I have done

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Items::ItemsController do
  describe "GET items#get_serialized_copy_of_item" do
     it "renders 204 status code" do
      get "/items/get_serialized_copy_of_item/dfsdf"
      expect(last_response.status).to eq(204)
    end
  end
end
```

Error: I am getting routing error

```
F

Failures:

  1) Items::ItemsController GET items#item renders 204 status code
     Failure/Error: get "/items/get_serialized_copy_of_item/dfsdf"
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:controller=>"items/items", :action=>"/items/get_serialized_copy_of_item/dfsdf"}
     # ./spec/controllers/items/items_controller_spec.rb:6:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.01576 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/items/items_controller_spec.rb:5 # Items::itemsController GET items#item renders 204 status code
```

bundle exec rake routes

```
                                       GET    `items/get_serialized_copy_of_item/:id(.:format)                            items/items#get_serialized_copy_of_item`
```

Thanks

Comment: can you please add the output of `bundle exec rake routes` to the end of your question?

Comment: @sixty4bit Added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RSpec assumes the controller name from the name of the test. Note the example in [this doc](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-3/docs/controller-specs/controller-spec):

```
describe WidgetsController do
  describe "GET index" do
    it "has a 200 status code" do
      get :index
      response.code.should eq("200")
    end
  end
end
```

Here RSpec already knows the `widgets` part of the path because of `describe WidgetsController`, so the `get` method only takes `:index` as an argument.

To translate that to your case:

```
describe Items::ItemsController do
  describe "GET get_serialized_copy_of_item" do
     it "renders 204 status code" do
      get :get_serialized_copy_of_item, id: 'sdf'

      expect(response.status).to eq(204)
    end
  end
end
```

1. You only need to pass the name of the action to the `get()` method, not the entire path.
2. You need to include the `:id` param as a second argument to `get()`
3. It seems like `namespace` is the wrong way to do the routing here. Try changing your route definitions to this:

> ```
> resources :items do 
>   member do 
>     get :get_serialized_copy
>   end
> end
> ```

This will generate the following route:

```
➜  bundle exec rake routes
   Prefix Verb   URI Pattern     

    Controller#Action
get_serialized_copy_item GET    /items/:id/get_serialized_copy(.:format) items#get_serialized_copy
```

For this you want to have your `ItemsController` in `app/controllers/items_controller.rb`

Comment: I tried but I am getting same error. I also tried with `describe ItemsController`

Comment: This answer looks correct to me. Are you still getting exactly this: `No route matches {:controller=>"items/items", :action=>"/items/get_serialized_copy_of_item/dfsdf"}` ?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh, yes  `ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:id=>"sdf", :controller=>"items/items", :action=>"get_serialized_copy_of_item"}`

Comment: @kavin that is definitely not the same error as before. notice the problem is still the `:controller` part: it says no route is matching the controller `items/items`. so something is wrong in your routing and/or namespacing of things

Comment: @kavin I've added more to the end of my answer about how you can fix your routing

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see there isn't any nesting.

If so, you should be calling `ItemsController` instead of `Items::ItemsController`.

**items_controller_spec:**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ItemsController do
  describe "GET #get_serialized_copy_of_item" do
     it "renders 204 status code" do
      get "/items/get_serialized_copy_of_item/dfsdf"
      expect(last_response.status).to eq(204)
    end
  end
end
```